# Como puedo mostrar los modelos según la marca?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

Buenas en mi formulario de agregar producto tengo los campos marca y modelo. Ambos son campos de select. Mi problema es que sea la marca que seleccione me trae todos los modelos, pero lo que estoy buscando hacer es que al seleccionar la marca X después el select de modelos sea solo opciones de modelos pertenecientes a esa marca.

Este es mi modelo Bran:

```
   class Brand extends Model
{
  public function modelo(){
      return $this->hasMany(ModelP::class, 'model_id', 'id');
  }

  public function producto(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_id', 'id');
  }
}
```

Mi modelo ModelP:

```
    class ModelP extends Model
 {
      protected $table = 'models';

  public function marca(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class, 'brand_id', 'id');
  }


}
```

Mi modelo Product:

```
  class Product extends Model
{



  public function ptype(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Ptype::class,'ptype_id','id'); 
  }

  public function marca(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class, 'brand_id', 'id'); 
  }

  public function modelo(){
      return $this->belongsTo(ModelP::class, 'model_id', 'id'); 
  }


}
```

Y estos son los campos de mi vista con los select:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="brand_id">Marca</label>
                        <select name="brand_id" class="form-control">
                          <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                          @foreach ($brands as $brand)
                          <option value="{{ $brand->id }}">{{ $brand->brandName }}</option>
                          @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="model_id">Modelo</label>
                        <select name="model_id" class="form-control">
                          <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                          @foreach ($models as $model)
                          <option value="{{ $model->id }}">{{ $model->modelName }}</option>
                          @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Queria saber como identificar cual fue la marca seleccionada y que aparezcan solo los modelos relacionados a esa marca seleccionada.

Comment: mmm y que has hecho? tienes que implementar ajax en el select de marca y el select de modelo tiene que ser dinamico... para que la respuesta del ajax pueda llenarlo correctamente....

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que realizar es una llamada de `AJAX`, pero primero necesitas crear una ruta en tu archivo `web.php` y añadir la ruta que va a usar la llamada:

```
Route::get('/get-model/{brand_id}', 'YourController@getModelsByBrand');
```

Ahora tienes que crear una nueva función en tu controlador, que será la encargada de conseguir la información solicitada según los parámetros:

```
public function getModelsByBrand($brand_id) {
    return json_encode(ModelP::whereBrandId($brand_id)->get());
}
```

Y por último tu llamada `AJAX` que se ejecutará en cuanto se cambie el valor del `select` de marcas:

```js
$('select[name="brand_id"]').on('change', function (e) {
    var brand = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/get-model/' + brand,
        success: function success(data) {

            // Quitar todas las opciones del select
            $('select name="model_id"').children('option').remove();

            // Preparar los datos para añadir cada opción nueva al select
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            for(let i = 0; i < data.lenght; i++){
                $('select name="model_id"').append('<option value="' + data[i]['id'] + '" selected="selected">' + data[i]['modelName'] + ' </option>');
            }
        },
        error: function error(data) {
            console.log("Error", data);
        }
    });
});
```

Y listo, con eso se hace el proceso completo